# Error 90 (Connection refused) when connecting to Remedy via Java

Tags: java, remedy

On my company network we run Remedy 7.64 and want to create Incidents automatically. I setup the development environment using IntelliJ IDEA and the ARAPI-files  for my server version. We have no administration access to the server to change anything over there.

The error says

> ERROR (90): Can't connect to AR System-Server; Connection refused:
> connect <host>.

Mysteriously i can connect to the Web-Interface using Chrome, i can ping the host, i can access it via the Driver & the official Remedy Client and the java tool can get the source code of the web-interface of it as well, so it obviously is possible to connect to the host but the difficulty is somewhere else.

This is my simple demo file

```
import com.bmc.arsys.api.*;
public static void main(String [ ] args)
{
    ARServerUser ctx = new ARServerUser();
    ctx.setServer("<server>");
    ctx.setUser("<user>");
    ctx.setPassword("<pass>");

    try {
        ctx.login();
        System.out.println("works");
    } catch (ARException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the list of dependancies

> - 1.8 (java version "1.8.0_65")
> - [Module source ]
> - groovy-2.4.5
> - log4j-1.2.14.jar
> - arapi7604_build002.jar

Comment: I just found out that the same issue exists for the official java driver as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide port number in which AR server is listening on. "ERROR (90): Can't connect to AR System-Server; Connection refused: connect ." means that the server refused to connect as you haven't mentioned the port number to connect. Normally people use 37000 as the AR server port number, but you have to check with your Remedy Admin to know this.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same error. My issue was that I tried to connect using the full url as `<server>` ("`https://...`"). Using just the name of the server worked.